# Find top 2 venues based on top 3 years with most concerts held?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am not sure if the question is written well by the exercise but to answer this question I split it into 2 questions.

1. What were the top 3 years with the most concerts held?
2. Based on the top years, which 2 venues had the most concert held during this period?

this is my dataset

```
  df = {"year":["2017","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2019","2019","2019",'2019',"2019","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2021","2021","2021","2021","2021","2022",'2022','2023'],
        "venue":["V2","V1","V2","V2","V2","V2","V1","V1","V2","V2","V5","V1","V2","V2","V3","V3","V3","V3","V4","V4","V5","V1","V6","V3"]}
```

To answer Q1,

```
stadium_count_per_year= df.groupby('year').agg({'venue':'count'})
highest_concert_yr = stadium_count_per_year[stadium_count_per_year["venue"] >= stadium_count_per_year["venue"].max()]
```

I found that 2018,2019,2020,2021 were the top 3 years with all having 5 concerts held.

To answer Q2,
I thought I could do this:

```
stadium_count = df.groupby("venue","year").agg({"venue":'count'})
```

However, this is incorrect. What method should I use to solve this question?

I am expecting question 2 to be something like this:

Year Venue

2018 V2

2020 V3

Comment: avoid `groupby.count`/`groupby.agg` for this purpose, `value_counts` is more efficient ;)

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit ambiguous because you have ties. I would use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) here and [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) slicing to filter the years:

```
# find the 3 years with most concerts
top = df['year'].value_counts().nlargest(3, keep='all').index
# ['2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']
# NB. all are equal with 5 concerts

# then only keep the years identified above and repeat the logic
df.loc[df['year'].isin(top), 'venue'].value_counts().nlargest(2, keep='all')
```

*NB. if you really want to consider the top N, even if there are ties, then use `keep='first'` in `nlargest`, but this might give ambiguous results depending on the order of the rows.*

Output:

```
venue
V2    8
V1    4
V3    4
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow your approach, you just need to use `isin` with years. After that, the rest is easy.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"year": ["2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", '2019', "2019", "2020", "2020",
                            "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2022", '2022', '2023'],
                   "venue": ["V2", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V1", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V5", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V3", "V3", "V3",
                             "V3", "V4", "V4", "V5", "V1", "V6", "V3"]})



stadium_count_per_year = df.groupby('year').agg({'venue':'count'})['venue']
max_years = stadium_count_per_year.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[2]
yrs = stadium_count_per_year[stadium_count_per_year >= max_years].index.values

venue_count = df[df['year'].isin(yrs)].groupby('venue').count()['year']
max_venues = venue_count.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[1]
venues = venue_count[venue_count >= max_venues].index.values
print(yrs, venues)
```

Yields

```
['2018' '2019' '2020' '2021'] ['V1' 'V2' 'V3']
```